# Cython: Performance in Python of view_as_windows vs manual algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, numpy, cython

My environment is OS: Ubuntu and Language: Python + Cython.

I am having a bit of a quandary as to what path to pursue. I am using view_as_windows to slice up an image and return to me an array of all the patches created from slicing. I also created an algorithm that does pretty much the same thing to have more control over the slicing. I have tested both algorithms and they create exactly the results I want, my problem now is I need much faster performance so I am trying to cythonize things. I am very new to Cython so I haven't actually done any changes yet.

view_as_windows time per image: **0.0033s**

patches_by_col time per image: **0.057s**

---

Question:

Given these run-times, would I get better performance from cythonizing the manual algorithm or just keep using view_as_windows? 
I ask because I don't think I can cythonize view_as_windows since it gets called from numpy. I am testing with variable stride disabled (strideDivisor == 0 and imgRegion == 0). Image sizes are 1200 by 800.

> GetPatchesAndCoordByRow (manual code)

Parameters:

```
#Patch Image Settings: Should be 3x2 ratio for width to height
WIDTH = 60
HEIGHT = 40
CHANNELS = 1
ITERATIONS = 7
MULTIPLIER = 1.31
#Stride will be how big of a step each crop takes.
#If you dont want to crops to overlap, do same stride as width of image.
STRIDE = 6
# STRIDE_IMREG_DIV decreases normal stride inside an image region
    #Set amount by which to divide stride.
        #Ex: 2 would reduce stride by 50%, and generate 200% data
        #Ex contd: So it would output 40K patches instead of 20K
    #strideDivisor = 1.5
# IMG_REGION determines what % of image region will produce additional patches
    #Region of image to focus by decreasing stride. Ex: 0.5 would increase patches in inner 50% of image
    #imgRegion = 0.5
# Set STRIDE_IMREG_DIV and IMG_REGION = 0 to disable functionality.
STRIDE_IMREG_DIV = 0
IMG_REGION = 0
```

Source code:

```
def setVarStride(x2, y2, maxX, maxY, stride, div, imgReg, var):
    imgFocReg1 = imgReg/2
    imgFocReg2 = 1 - imgFocReg1

    if (var == 'x'):
        if ((x2 >= maxX*imgFocReg1) and (x2 <= maxX*imgFocReg2) and (y2 >= maxY*imgFocReg1) and (y2 <= maxY*imgFocReg2)):
            vStride = stride/div
        else:
            vStride = stride
    elif (var == 'y'):
        if ((y2 >= maxY*imgFocReg1) and (y2 <= maxY*imgFocReg2)):
            vStride = stride/div
        else:
            vStride = stride
    return vStride

def GetPatchesAndCoordByRow(image, patchHeight, patchWidth, stride, strideDivisor, imgRegion):
    x1 = 0
    y1 = 0
    x2 = patchWidth
    y2 = patchHeight
    croppedImageList = []
    maxX, maxY = image.size

    #Set variable stride to collect more data in a region of the image
    varStride = stride
    useVaraibleStride = True
    if (strideDivisor == 0 and imgRegion == 0):
        useVaraibleStride = False
    else:
        imgConcentration = (1 - imgRegion)*100
        print("Variable Stride ENABLED: Create more patches inside {0}% of the image.".format(imgConcentration))

    while y2 <= (maxY):
        while x2 <= (maxX):
            croppedImage = image.crop((x1,y1,x2,y2))
            croppedImageList.append((croppedImage,(x1, y1, x2, y2)))
            #Get 2x more patches in the center of the image
            if (useVaraibleStride):
                varStride = setVarStride(x2, y2, maxX, maxY, stride, strideDivisor, imgRegion, 'x')
            #Rows
            x1 += varStride
            x2 += varStride
            #--DEBUG
            #iX += 1
            #print("Row_{4} -> x1: {0}, y1: {1}, x2: {2}, y2: {3}".format(x1, y1, x2, y2,iX))

        #Get 2x more patches in the center of the image
        if (useVaraibleStride):
            varStride = setVarStride(x2, y2, maxX, maxY, stride, strideDivisor, imgRegion, 'y')
        #Columns
        x1  = 0
        x2  = patchWidth
        y1 += varStride
        y2 += varStride
        #--DEBUG
        #iY += 1
        #print("    Column_{4} -> x1: {0}, y1: {1}, x2: {2}, y2: {3}".format(x1, y1, x2, y2, iY))

    #Get patches at edge of image
    x1 = 0
    x2 = patchWidth
    y1 = maxY - patchHeight
    y2 = maxY
    #Bottom edge patches
    while x2 <= (maxX):
        #--DEBUG
        #iX += 1
        #print("Row_{4} -> x1: {0}, y1: {1}, x2: {2}, y2: {3}".format(x1, y1, x2, y2,iX))
        #--DEBUG
        croppedImage = image.crop((x1,y1,x2,y2))
        croppedImageList.append((croppedImage,(x1, y1, x2, y2)))
        #Rows
        x1 += stride
        x2 += stride
    #Right edge patches
    x1 = maxX - patchWidth
    x2 = maxX
    y1 = 0
    y2 = patchHeight
    while y2 <= (maxY):
        #--DEBUG
        #iY += 1
        #print("    Column_{4} -> x1: {0}, y1: {1}, x2: {2}, y2: {3}".format(x1, y1, x2, y2, iY))
        #--DEBUG
        croppedImage = image.crop((x1,y1,x2,y2))
        croppedImageList.append((croppedImage,(x1, y1, x2, y2)))
        #Columns
        y1 += stride
        y2 += stride
    #--DEBUG
    print("GetPatchesAndCoordByRow (Count={0}, W={1}, H={2}, Stride={3})".format(len(croppedImageList), int(patchWidth), int(patchHeight), int(stride)))

    return croppedImageList
```

> view_as_windows code

```
def CreatePatches(image, patchHeight, patchWidth, stride = 1):
    imageArray = numpy.asarray(image)
    patches = view_as_windows(imageArray, (patchHeight, patchWidth), stride)
    print("Raw Patches initial shape: {0}".format(patches.shape))
    return patches
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do much better than `view_as_windows`, as it is already very efficient as long as the input array is contiguous. I doubt even cythonizing it would make much difference. I looked into its implementation and was actually a bit impressed:

A numpy array is made up of an underlying data array (such as a `char *`) and an array of "strides", one for each dimension, that tell how far to move along the underlying array, for each single step along that dimension. [The implementation of `view_as_windows`](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/util/shape.py#L219) takes advantage of this by creating a new array that shares the same data array as its input, and simply inserts new "strides" to add dimensions that can be used to select a patch. This means it isn't returning "an array of all the patches" as you say, but it is only returning a single array, whose first dimensions act like indexes into an array of patches.

Thus, `view_as_windows` doesn't need to copy any data in your image to create the patches, nor does it need to create additional ndarray objects for each patch. The only time it needs to copy data is when its input array is not contiguous (e.g. it is a slice of a larger array). Even with Cython, I don't see how you can do very much better than this.

In your implementation, even assuming that `image.crop` is able to share data from the image, you are still creating an array of what looks like 1199x799 different `image` objects.

Have you confirmed that `view_as_windows` is where your algorithm spends most of its time?

Comment: I added additional information, specifically the Parameters part used to call the function. This is so you can see that this function is inside of a loop that iterates 7 times and increases the patch size by 1.31 times each time with a stride of 6. So in the end both algorithms create approximately 20K patches. The main reason why I created the manual algorithm is so I could save the coordinates of each patch. So then my only concern would be to get the correct coordinates per patch outside of view_as_windows. And there is other parts of the program to optimize but I'm doing each one at a time

Comment: When using `view_as_windows`, it seems like it would be faster to compute the absolute coordinates of each patch using `numpy.linspace` (or possibly `numpy.arange`) and `numpy.mgrid` rather than computing them in pure-python using `while` loops.

Comment: In fact, I think all you need is to use `numpy.mgrid[:width:stride,:height:stride]`. to get the absolute coordinates...

Comment: I have never used that function before and am not familiar with how I would implement this in conjunction with view_as_windows? How would numpy.mgrid[:width:stride,:height:stride] return to me the coordinates after view_as_windows has run if you're not passing it the array?
Also width and height are the patch with/height, not the full image dimensions. 
I looked up examples of how to use it but no examples used it in conjunction with view_as_windows.

Comment: iPython created this output with mgrid as you mentioned @codewarrior

`In[26]: coords
Out[26]: 
array([[[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
        [10, 10, 10, 10],
        [20, 20, 20, 20],
        [30, 30, 30, 30],
        [40, 40, 40, 40],
        [50, 50, 50, 50]],

       [[ 0, 10, 20, 30],
        [ 0, 10, 20, 30],
        [ 0, 10, 20, 30],
        [ 0, 10, 20, 30],
        [ 0, 10, 20, 30],
        [ 0, 10, 20, 30]]])
In[27]: coords.shape
Out[27]: (2, 6, 4)`

view_as_windows after first iteration
`In[20]: patches.shape
Out[20]: (117, 75, 40, 60)`

This means it created 117x75 patches of 40x60 pixels.

Comment: Did you try using the image width with `mgrid` instead of the patch width?

Comment: Yes, it still did not give the same results. I'm expecting 117x75 = 8775 patches from first iteration, and it gets nowhere near that

Comment: The idea is to use `mgrid` to obtain evenly-spaced coordinates across the image size using the same image size and stride(s) as were passed to view_as_windows. Calling view_as_windows with a 1200x800 image, a 60x40 patch size, and a stride of 6, I get an array of shape (191, 127, 60, 40). From  `numpy.mgrid[:width-patchWidth+1:stride, :height-patchHeight+1:stride]`, I get an array of shape (2, 191, 127). The coordinates in the `mgrid` array correspond to the coordinates of each patch relative to the whole image.

Comment: Thanks for the last tips. So I am putting it in ipython with these parameters: width = 1200, height = 800, patchWidth = 60, patchHeight = 40, stride = 10. My code looks like -- coord = numpy.mgrid[:width-patchWidth+1:stride, :height-patchHeight+1:stride]. The output of coord.shape = (2,115, 77), but it should be (2,117,75) same as view_as_windows. Am I missing something?

Comment: It seems like you have passed patchWidth and patchHeight to view_as_windows in the wrong order.

Comment: No it's the right order because I've seen the patch outputs and they are in landscape how I want them. Anyway I was able to figure it out, thanks!